# How to make a valid request to mysql with array of tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of tables of this type:

```
$tables = "`01_12_2014`,`02_02_2015`,`02_03_2015`,`03_08_2015`,`04_05_2015`,`05_01_2015`,`06_04_2015`,`06_07_2015`,`07_09_2015`";
```

they all have the same structure.

How can I get the value of each table, one query to the database

That does not work (error Column 'informer' in field list is ambiguous):

```
$tables_query = "SELECT `informer`, `count`, `site` FROM `$tables` WHERE site = 'nv'";
```

Comment: Use a UNION: `SELECT ... FROM table1 UNION SELECT ... FROM table2 ...`

Comment: P.S. `$tables` isn't an array.

Comment: As a follow up to what @Strawberry says... Why do you have table like this?  Please don't tell me you have a table for *each* day?  Why not just have **one** table and add a `date` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a string with (escaped) table names. It's not an array, although you can make it one using `explode`.

Once you have the table names in an array, you can build a `UNION` query with all of the table names.

```
<?php
$tables = "`01_12_2014`,`02_02_2015`,`02_03_2015`,`03_08_2015`,`04_05_2015`,`05_01_2015`,`06_04_2015`,`06_07_2015`,`07_09_2015`";
$tablenames = explode(',', $tables);

$table_queries = array();
foreach($tablenames as $table) {
  $table_queries[] = "SELECT `informer`, `count`, `site` FROM $table WHERE site = 'nv'";
}
$table_query_all = implode("\nUNION ALL\n", $table_queries);

echo $table_query_all;
```

But I have to second Strawberry's comment. ;)

Comment: You posted this mere seconds before I finished typing up the same answer! :-D

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM table1, table2, ...` syntax is the same as `FROM table1 JOIN table2 JOIN ...` which is not what you want here.

What you want to use is a `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION
...
```

Or with the "array" you have:

```
// You have a string, not an array
$tablesArray = explode(',', $tables);

// Loop over the tables and build a `SELECT` for each:
$selectQueries = array_map(function($table){
    return "SELECT `informer`, `count`, `site` FROM {$table} WHERE `site` = 'nv'";
}, $tablesArray);

// Combine it all into one query
$tables_query = implode(' UNION ', $selectQueries);
```